# Переносимость приложения. Проблема с Яндекс.Картами

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api

Доброго времени суток! При написании приложения, использующего **Яндекс.Карты**, столкнулся с проблемой переносимости на разные версии платформы.

Изначально начинал писать на версии **android 2.1**, так как наивно полагал, что на более старших версиях будет работать. Запускал для проверки всегда на эмуляторе с **android 2.1** и на телефоне друга с **android 2.2** все работало хорошо, на днях же, попробовал запустить на **android 2.3**(планшет) и тут возникли проблемы с запуском, даже открывать отказался, на телефоне же с **android 2.3** не работали только карты, остальное все запускалось. Планшет с **android 3.0** открывает, но иногда приложение вылетает.

Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой или кто-то знает, куда следует капать.

Comment: Нужно снимать лог и смотреть. Другого рецепта никто не даст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего связано с тем, что приложение требует наличия телефонных или иных функций. Явно пропишите в манифесте:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

По-моему наличие телефонных функций требуется по умолчанию (могу ошибаться) - поэтому пропишите явно отказ от них. Но если в коде используются телефонные функции, то тут сложнее - хотя тоже можно решить через рефлексию.

Вторая возможная причина - это проблема с поддержкой больших экранов (хотя малореально). Но на всякий случай пропишите в манифесте поддержку всех экранов:

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

Ну и наконец 3-я причина: скомпилируйте под 2.3 с декларацией поддержки младших версий:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Я в свое время немало намучился и в итоге пришел к таким модификациям.